# New IP address does not persist after restart

Tags: linux, network-programming

I have some code that uses system commands to set the IP address and default gateway in Linux.

It works, but when the Linux OS is restarted, it reverts back to the old IP address.

Here are the commands used, addresses changed here.

```
  ip link set eth1 down
  ifconfig eth1 0.0.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
  route add default gw 0.0.1.2 eth1
  ip link set eth1 up
```

Is there another place in Linux where the IP address needs to be set, that 'ifconfig' does not change?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Which linux distro are you using?

Comment: The version is Linux EconoliteATC 2.6.35.12.  This is a specialized device, in this case its from the company Econolite.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thanks jww.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For Static IP address assignment**

1. Debian/Ubuntu Base Distro :- you can edit /etc/network/interfaces file, which contains information about the Network Configuration.
2. RedHat/CentOS Base Distro, you can edit /etc/sysconfig/network file.
3. If you can't find either of the files, then append the following commands to either ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc file in your linux machine

   ```
   ip link set eth1 down
   ifconfig eth1 0.0.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
   route add default gw 0.0.1.2 eth1
   ip link set eth1 up
   ```

   ~./bashrc is user specific file and /etc/bash.bashrc is common for all users. Whenever the any user login to system, and you have added the mentioned commands in /etc/bash.bashrc file, then these commands will be executed by the system. The user won't have to execute these commands manually.

For Further Details visit:- http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialNetworking.html

Comment: Thanks. I found the network/interfaces file. This file does not change when I run 'ifconfig', so I will add a method to edit this file with the new values.